# VAO Not Rendering, OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I have been trying to get an array object to render to a window for a while now. It seems like the GLEW functions aren't running. The result should be a triangle rendered to the output window. It may be that the functions are deprecated or that there is some function missing.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
#include <string_view>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <stdio.h>   


using namespace std; 

GLuint vao = 0;
GLuint vbo = 0;

int main(void) {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 640, "OpenGL Example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    glewInit();
    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    }; 
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao); 
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof(GLfloat), &g_vertex_buffer_data[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
     
     
    //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


    const float DEG2RAD = 3.14159 / 180; 
    float r = 0.0;
    float g = 0.3;
    float b = 0.6; 
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        //Setup View
        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float)height;
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
         
        //Drawing
        glColor3f(r, g, b);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &g_vertex_buffer_data[0]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); 
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 
        //Swap buffer and check for events
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate;
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

A triangle should be rendered to the window.

Comment: _"It seems like the GLEW functions aren't running"_  What makes you say that?  What actually happened?  Be careful to report _observations_, not _conclusions_.

Comment: Why are you just...evaluating `glfwTerminate` there at the end?

Answer (score 2):

VAOs are in the standard since OpenGL Version 3.0, so they are not in OpenGL Version 2.0 (see [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)). Alternatively, VAOs are also available through an extension: [`GL_ARB_vertex_array_object`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_vertex_array_object.txt).

Answer (score 0):

The buffer data isn't quite right. Now it's appearing.

```
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        };
```